# assert(len(content) == 3) AssertionError

Tags: python, assert

I got this error

```
cluster.py", line 20, in load_data
   distance, num, max_dis, min_dis = load_data(distance_file)
    assert(len(content) == 3)
AssertionError
```

the code of cluster.py

```
with open(distance_file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            content = line.strip().split(' ')
            assert(len(content) == 3)
            idx1, idx2, dis = int(content[0]), int(content[1]), float(content[2])
```

sample of data like

```
1   1   0.000000
1   2   26.232388
1   3   44.486252
1   4   47.168839
1   5   37.593277
```

sample of the other file is

```
-82.3602 158.46
-91.0108 133.695
-125.815 148.936
-129.259 153.42
```

Comment: Never do `.split(' ')` unless you *specifically* want to split on only a single space. I imagine you actually wanted `.split()`, which splits on one or more arbitrary whitespace characters.  Also, you could easily debug this yourself by adding `print(content)` on the line before the `assert`.

Comment: Yeah, there are clearly multiple spaces between those columns...

Comment: i tried it and error still assert(len(content) == 3) AssertionError

Comment: Did you try `print(content)`? Because if you do it should become apparent why it is failing, You should post that output.

Comment: Also, your traceback does not match the code - if you can demonstrate that it is actually not related to `split()` I can re-open the question.

Comment: i got the code from here github.com/lanbing510/DensityPeakCluster/blob/master/cluster.py i checked it again but it didn't work my data as I posted here and as the example of the code

Comment: Are you sure that _every_ line in the file has three columns?

Comment: yes. because there is another class of code I run it and got the results as the example

Comment: @user1 The code you posted does not exist exactly in the code that you linked, which makes me believe you have a custom version that you have edited. Therefore, *please* insert `print(content)` before the `assert` statement. Without the output of that it is literally impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: i wrote it and got the first values from another file as ['-82.3602', '158.46']
I will edit the post with samples of another file but I thought It got values from distance because I have two file .. one for x and y columns and the other for the distances between them

Comment: You have your answer right there - that other file has only two columns, so your assertion that the length is 3 fails.

Comment: the problem is the code is opensource and should work so I wonder why this error appeared and the data is appropriate like the code example

Comment: it will be 2 ? did you mean that ?

Comment: but how it will 2 and the next line is             idx1, idx2, dis = int(content[0]), int(content[1]), float(content[2]) that will accept 3 ?

Comment: The length of `['-82.3602', '158.46']` is 2. I cannot help you with why the author wrote the code that way, and if you are or are not using the code correctly, but if you give a file with two columns it will fail because the length is 2, not 3.

Comment: "but how it will 2 and the next line is idx1, idx2, dis = int(content[0]), int(content[1]), float(content[2]) that will accept 3" This is why the `assert` is there, to avoid an error on that line. This is not the forum to discuss design decisions of an open source project. Please file an issue on that GitHub page.

Comment: @SethMMorton you are right i checked the files and the wrong was in the file I used so I exchanged it with split() and worked but got another problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082634/how-can-i-handle-the-code-to-avoid-killed of you can help .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an `AssertionError`, because the assertion fails, and it fails, because you are splitting on 1 space, but the values are separated by 2 spaces. To circumvent this, use split without arguments, which will split at arbitrary amounts of spaces:

```py
content = line.strip().split()
```

Comment: i tried it and error still assert(len(content) == 3)
AssertionError

Comment: @user1 sorry, but i tried it and it works